# Possible bug with page reporting total users earning a badge that can be awarded multiple times

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I'm actively participating in the private beta of [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), and I recently earned the Enlightened badge. (Woot!) I checked to see who else had earned it by going to [tex.stackexchange.com/badges/19/enlightened](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/19/enlightened). At the time I'm writing, it reports that

> 3 Users earned this badge. Recently awarded to:
>
> 6h ago    How can I make an enumerate list start at something other than 1 in LaTeX? — ShreevatsaR 49629
>
> 8h ago    How to wrap text around a figure? — vanden 427114
>
> 12h ago   \eqnarray vs \align — ShreevatsaR 49629

Since the badge has been awarded 3 times, but only to 2 users, the text seems wrong. Ought it not say either:

> This badge has been awarded 3 times

or

> This badge has been awarded 3 times to a total of 2 users?

I grant that this isn't the ugliest bug in the world. But, it does still seem a bug.

Comment: Aww, I saw the URL and thought the Texas site had made it to beta.

Comment: @mmyers Wow, that actually is a proposal; I thought you were joking

Comment: @mmyers @michaelmrozek I thought you *both* were joking.

Answer (score 2):

The badge page title has now been changed to:

> This badge has been awarded N times.

This is in the next build.